# Respond to a SSH prompt before first command with ruby and Net::SSH

Tags: ruby, ssh, net-ssh

I'm trying to connect, using Net::SSH, to a server that immediately after
login executes a script that requires input from user. The user has to enter "1" or "2" and will receive some data via in the terminal afterwards.

My problem is that, although I am able to connect, I can not figure out a way to send "1\n" to the server and to receive the output.

The following code stops at "INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[80906b74]: channel_open_confirmation: 0 0 0 32768".

Using channel.exec( "1\n" ) instead of channel.send_data unsurprisingly does not work either.

```
Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', :password => "pass", :auth_methods => ["password"], :verbose => :debug) do |session|

  session.open_channel do |channel|

    channel.on_data do |ch, data|
      STDOUT.print data
    end 

    channel.send_data( "1\n")

  end

  session.loop
end
```

Any ideas, anyone?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you verify that your `send_data` call is happening *after* you get the prompt from the remote server?  Try constructing a `channel.on_data` block around your `send_data` call so that you can verify that you get the expected prompt from the server before you send a response.

You might not want to be using `exec` here.  From the docs for Net::SSH::Connection::Channel:

> Sends a channel request asking that
>   the given command be invoked.

You are wanting to send a text string to reply to a prompt, not invoke a command.  The docs show `exec` being used to send full CLI commands like "ls -l /home".

Instead, `send_data` is probably what you want.  The docs show it used to send arbitrary text such as `channel.send_data("the password\n")`.  Note, however, this sentence in the docs:

> Note that it does not immediately send
>   the data across the channel, but
>   instead merely appends the given data
>   to the channel‘s output buffer,
>   preparatory to being packaged up and
>   sent out the next time the connection
>   is accepting data.

You might want to take a look at [`channel.request_pty`](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/ssh/v2/api/classes/Net/SSH/Connection/Channel.html#M000213).  It appears to be designed for interaction with a console-based application.

If you are trying to (in essence) script an SSH session that you would normally do manually, you may find it easier to use an `expect`-like interface (for example, a gem like [sshExpect](http://rubyforge.org/projects/sshexpect/) might be worth a try).

Comment: I have actually tried using channel.request_pty, the request succeeds, but the data is neither being sent, nor received afterwards (using channel.send_data)

Comment: How can I verify whether I get a prompt from the remote server?

Comment: In your `channel.on_data do |ch, data| ... end` block, the variable "data" will hold the data sent to you from the server.  Inside that block, `puts` it to the console/logfile and inspect it visually.  Once you see what format the server's prompt will be in, you can write code to parse it.  You might try something like `puts "got data: #{data.inspect}"`.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for the pointers. I have been able to put my finger on the problem – besides using channel.request_pty it was also necessary to request a shell. The following finally works as expected:

```
Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', :password => "pass", :auth_methods => ["password"]) do |session|

  session.open_channel do |channel|

    channel.request_pty do |ch, success| 
      raise "Error requesting pty" unless success 

      ch.send_channel_request("shell") do |ch, success| 
        raise "Error opening shell" unless success  
      end  
    end

    channel.on_data do |ch, data|
      STDOUT.print data
    end 

    channel.on_extended_data do |ch, type, data|
      STDOUT.print "Error: #{data}\n"
    end

    channel.send_data( "1\n" )

    session.loop
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly familiar with the Net::SSH libs so I can't help with that per-se but it sounds like you could achieve what you want using **Capistrano**.

For example I have a capistrano task which connects to a remote server, runs a command which expects input and then continues. Capistrano takes care of the remote i/o. Maybe that could be a solution for you?

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I execute `"1\n"` in a shell the reply I get is: `bash: 1: command not found`

If I execute `echo "1"` I get: `1`

Are you sure you want to try to execute the text you are sending? Maybe you were looking for something like:

```
output = ""
Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', :password => "pass") do |ssh|
   output = ssh.exec! "echo 1"
end
puts output
```

Comment: The problem is, I want to send "1\n" to the STDIN of the script waiting on the other end.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not just opening up a socket and listening on the remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proficient with that lib, but on SSH you can open multiple channels.  Maybe the server only responds to the first default channel and if you open another one you get a fresh shell.